# php count 2 parameters error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a function that brings me the sum of the records in my database that meet 2 conditions.

i start like this

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion){

         $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];
    }
```

I need to add one more field to the account.
the ID department parameter which I want to assign to only tell me the tickets or reports of that department

[using the previous function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H29m1.png)

When I'm trying to account for that user's tickets in that department using this function

```
function listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id){

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                                     FROM ticket as t
                                     JOIN usuario AS u
                                     ON t.id_usuario = u.id
                                     WHERE t.status <> '3' AND u.id_departamento = ".$id."") 
                                     or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

i get this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfm9p.png)

Comment: What is `$id`???

Comment: Can you show the full error message, please?

Comment: Fairly standard debugging procedure would be to print out `$consulta` and see what you're *actually* attempting to run on the database and work from there...

Comment: If you're going to select any other specific columns, you can't use `*` without qualifying it with a table name, so you need `t.*` or `u.*`, or just select the columns you need and don't use `*` at all.

Comment: @AbraCadaver u.id_departamento = ".$id."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is just the formatting of your post, but the `*` can't be used on a query when you are selecting other specific fields, you can use the function like this

```
function listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id) {

$query = "SELECT t.field1, u.field_2, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, "
        . "t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, "
        . "t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion "
        . "FROM ticket as t "
        . "JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id "
        . "WHERE t.status <> '3' "
        . "AND u.id_departamento = " . $id . " "
        . "ORDER BY t.id DESC ";   
if($consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query)){
   return $consulta; 
} else {
    die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
}    
}
```

**Or just select everything**

```
function listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id) {

$query = "SELECT * "
        . "FROM ticket as t "
        . "JOIN usuario AS u ON t.id_usuario = u.id "
        . "WHERE t.status <> '3' "
        . "AND u.id_departamento = " . $id . " "
        . "ORDER BY t.id DESC ";   
if($consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query)){
   return $consulta; 
} else {
    die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
}    
}
```

**Counting the rows**

`$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);`

[mysqli_query documentation **(en)**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

[Here you can check the documentation about mysqli_query **(En Español Juan)**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Hope my answer helps you.

### Edit, fetch all the results

You can do it with a procedure like this one

```
    function getTheAssocArrayOfMyQuery($consulta){
    $return= array();
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        array_push($return, $consulta);
    }
    return $return;
    }
```

**Or, using `mysqli_fetch_all()`**

```
     $this_is_the_array_i_will_use = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

[**`mysqli_fetch_all()` manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Will edit, if i find an **easier** answer. You should read the links posted on my answer, some documentation about the functions you need there won't be useless.

Comment: It's not that it's useless, I'm going to edit the question giving more information @francisco Hahn